# Sitecore log files "Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached"

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

Below is an extract of my log files. I have executed a load test on our server. As the load test progresses I have noticed following logs being created in the log,
"Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached.". Load test was executed on the home page, which has Sitecore analytics tracking.

```
460 17:21:31 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
4108 17:21:31 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
1072 17:22:32 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
2124 17:23:33 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
3468 17:24:00 WARN  Long running operation: Long running rule set: /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Rules/Session End/Rules
3468 17:24:01 WARN  Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached. Dropped 1 changeset(s).
3520 17:24:03 WARN  Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached. Dropped 26 changeset(s).
1072 17:24:05 WARN  Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached. Dropped 51 changeset(s).
2672 17:24:06 WARN  Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached. Dropped 76 changeset(s).
4516 17:24:08 WARN  Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached. Dropped 101 changeset(s).
4360 17:24:10 WARN  Analytics: Max size of insert queue reached. Dropped 126 changeset(s).
```

What is happening over here, can anyone explains this? 
With the time memory usage goes up to  maximum (7.96GB), and even though the load test finishes, memory remains at 7.96GB forever :). 
(Sitecore v6.6)

Comment: Try to increase `Analytics.MaxQueueSize` setting or descrease `Analytics.TrackerChanges.FlushInterval`. Does your test only open single home page and closes the browser? I don't think the memory usage is related to this warning log.

Comment: Did this help you out !?

Comment: Tried both. But was not helpful. May be I was trying a heavy load test, which will anyways go beyond the buffer. Anyways I was after the memory issues, figured out that issue. Thanks for your help on this :).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is that your Sql server or Web server cannot process the DMS/OMS tracking records fast enough. 
This is possibly a performance issue of the Analytics DB. 
Has the DB grown too big? 
Is the server low on memory? 
Are search bots logged?
Consider moving some data to a Data Warehouse.